# Having trouble reading a local Json file in my uwp project for school

Tags: uwp

I'm creating a little UWP application for one of my class papers and am trying to read a json file i have created and verified with jsonlint. If you can't already tell im a bit of a noob with uwp could someone please help point me in the right direction to look for the solution?

I am trying to read the json and put the contents into a listbox. the problem is i continue to get an error.

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 2, position 3.

I feel like my codebehind is correct and my json is correct but obviously not.

Here is the codebehind

```
private async void LoadData()
        {
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///questList.json"));

            string jsonText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

            List<string> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonText);
            foreach (string item in items)
            {
                questList.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

and this is the json

```
[
  {
    "taderName": "Prapor",
    "quests": [
      {
        "title": "Debut",
        "objectives": [
          {
            "objective": "Eliminate 5 scavs all over the Tarkov Territory"
          },
          {
            "objective": "Obtain and hand over 2 MP-133 12ga shotguns"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "taderName": "therapist",
    "quests": [
      {
        "title": "derka",
        "objectives": [
          {
            "objective": "Eliminate 5 scavs all over the Tarkov Territory"
          },
          {
            "objective": "Obtain and hand over 2 MP-133 12ga shotguns"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is composed of items with the same structure. It is not a string object so you can't use string as the type. Please create your own class which corresponding to the item structure of the JSON.

Please check the following code. I created a `Root` class, a `Quest` class and a `Objective` class to handle the JSON values.

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string jsonText = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"taderName\": \"Prapor\",\r\n    \"quests\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"title\": \"Debut\",\r\n        \"objectives\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"objective\": \"Eliminate 5 scavs all over the Tarkov Territory\"\r\n          },\r\n          {\r\n            \"objective\": \"Obtain and hand over 2 MP-133 12ga shotguns\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"taderName\": \"therapist\",\r\n    \"quests\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"title\": \"derka\",\r\n        \"objectives\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"objective\": \"Eliminate 5 scavs all over the Tarkov Territory\"\r\n          },\r\n          {\r\n            \"objective\": \"Obtain and hand over 2 MP-133 12ga shotguns\"\r\n          }\r\n        ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n]";

        List<Root> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(jsonText);
        foreach (Root item in items)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.taderName);
        }
    }
}

public class Objective
{
    public string objective { get; set; }
}

public class Quest
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<Objective> objectives { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string taderName { get; set; }
    public List<Quest> quests { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. With your help I was able to get onto the right track.